# How to update column with multiple conditions taking a corresponding value from another column Python Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

The output is more like the following SQL statement.

```
   UPDATE table_A SET final=(cs+fhfa+sz)/3 WHERE cs IS NOT NULL AND fhfa IS NOT NULL AND sz IS NOT NULL;
```

Here cs+fhfa+sz are all individual columns in the sql table ( and in dataframe)

If I want to convert this SQL statement to pandas operation in python, this will be more like :

```
   df['div_3'] = (df.cs+df.fhfa+df.sz) /3
   df['final'] = df.loc[(df['cs'] != None) & (df['fhfa'] != None) & (df['sz'] != None) ] = df['div_3']
```

But this does not guarantee "corresponding values" being put finally. How to achieve this??

Do i really need to create another column div_3 with all the sum of 3 columns? Can this be done without another column creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter on `pd.Series.notnull` and call `mean`.

```
c = ['cs', 'fhfa', 'sz']
df['final'] = df[df[c].notnull().all(1)][c].mean(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[:, 'final'] = df.loc[df[['cs','fhfa','sz']].notnull().all(1), ['cs','fhfa','sz']].sum(1)/3
```

`.all(1)` - is the same as `.all(axis=1)`, which means - all values in each **row** must be `True`

Comment: I think it's mean.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yeah, i've noticed it now. But if i would use it - it would be too similar to your answer... ;-)

Comment: Aha, no problem. You found another way and still nailed the answer, as always.

Comment: Wish I could accept both the answers :). THanks guys, but please explain all(1) , what the bracket 1 means

Comment: @Viv, me, personally, like cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer more ;-)